# How to test virtual machine performance in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: operating-system, ubuntu-14.04, virtual-machine, xml-rpc, opennebula

I am using xml-rpc to integrate opennebula into my own cloud dashboard. I need to test the vm performance. Suggest me any tools to test the vm. How to do that in ubuntu14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Use UnixBench (the best free benchmarking tool available) as follows:

```
$apt-get install libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxext-dev perl perl-modules make gcc
$wget http://byte-unixbench.googlecode.com/files/UnixBench5.1.3.tgz 
$tar xvf UnixBench5.1.3.tgz
$cd UnixBench
$./Run
```

For details about every test executed, visit:

https://github.com/kdlucas/byte-unixbench